# Magento menu with submenu

Tags: magento2, menu, submenu

I added my code to my custom header phtml:

```
<?php
                              $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                              $catId = 2; 
                              $subCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
                              $subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories();
                              $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
                              $hasSubcategories = count($subCats) > 0;
                           ?>

                           <?php 
                           
                           foreach ($subCats as $subcat) {
                              $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                              $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
                              ?>
                             
                              
                              <li class="level1 dontsplit parent">
                                       <a class="level1 has-children" href="<?php echo $subcaturl . '?cat=' . $_category->getId() ?>"><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?> (<?php echo $product_count = $_category->getProductCount();?>)</a>
                                       <?php
                                          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                                          $object_managertwo = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                                          $subcatslevelthird = $object_managertwo->getChildrenCategories();
                                       ?>
                                          <?php if ($subcatslevelthird->count() > 0) { ?>
                                             <ul class="level1">
                                                <?php
                                                   foreach ($subcatslevelthird as $subcatthird) {
                                                      $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
                                                      $subcaturl = $subcatthird->getUrl();
                                                ?>
                                                   
                                                   <li class="level2 dontsplit">
                                                      <a class="level2" href="<?php echo $subcaturl ?>"><?php echo $subcatthird->getName(); ?> (<?php echo $subcatthird = $_category->getProductCount();?>)</a>   
                                                   </li>
                                                   
                                                <?php } ?>
                                             </ul>
                                    <?php } ?>
                              </li>
                        <?php } ?>
```

all working properly except adding class to li element, i need display class **parent** - only for if menu has submenu, whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$catId = 2;
$subCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
$subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$hasSubcategories = count($subCats) > 0;
?>

<?php

foreach ($subCats as $subcat) {
$_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
$subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$object_managertwo = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
$subcatslevelthird = $object_managertwo->getChildrenCategories();
$parentClass = "";
if($subcatslevelthird->count() > 0){
    $parentClass = "parent";
}
?>


<li class="level1 dontsplit <?php echo $parentClass; ?>">
    <a class="level1 has-children" href="<?php echo $subcaturl . '?cat=' . $_category->getId() ?>"><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?> (<?php echo $product_count = $_category->getProductCount();?>)</a>
    <?php if ($subcatslevelthird->count() > 0) { ?>
    <ul class="level1">
        <?php
        foreach ($subcatslevelthird as $subcatthird) {
        $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
        $subcaturl = $subcatthird->getUrl();
        ?>

        <li class="level2 dontsplit">
            <a class="level2" href="<?php echo $subcaturl ?>"><?php echo $subcatthird->getName(); ?> (<?php echo $subcatthird = $_category->getProductCount();?>)</a>
        </li>

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

I have loaded sub categories first before adding 1st level `li` then check if count of child categories available, then added the class `parent`

Hope this will help you